# Floor drain in goat shelter

Tags: drain, floor, shed

I’m building a goat shelter a bit above grade. It’s essentially a 10x10 shed that will house our 5-8 goats. It’s up on concrete pillars, the closest to grade is 6” and about 18” at the highest point.

I plan on using plywood flooring and covering it with a single sheet of vinyl. I’d love to put a floor drain in with a pipe that runs out into our forest so that I can pressure wash the house every 6m or so. My question is, how do I put a drain in so that it is at least level, if not recessed with the floor?

Comment: not sure I understand the question

Comment: You reckon vinyl is tough enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are floor drains for use with sheet flooring,  the flange (funnel)  part of the drain installs before the floor covering. you will need to cut and recess the subfloor to accept the flange before laying the vinyl. lay the vinyl an seal it to the flange install the grate bezel and finally the grate. (there also plumbing to do on the underside)

Personally I'd be looking for an industrial floor treatment (not vinyl) to withstand hooved traffic.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a specific name I should be looking for? I’m hoping the vinyl will stand up because of the cushioned mats and straw on top. I was also considering a garage floor liner I saw.

Comment: I searched "floor drain for vinyl" and found a locally manufactured product.